# How to add values within rows in an array but keep the results from each matrix separately

Tags: r, arrays, sum

I have an array and I want to add the values in each row of each matrix. I dont't want to get the total value of each row across all the matrices of the array but the sum of each row individually for each matrix. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output. YOu could use `apply(arr1, 1, rowSums)`

Comment: Not clear from the comments If you have an array lik `a <- array(1:36, c(3, 4, 3))` then `rowSums(a[, , 1])#
[1] 22 26 30` and the `apply` output for the first one is
`> apply(a, 1, colSums)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   22   26   30...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the array and then do `colSums`

```
apply(a, 1, colSums)
```

Or `rowSums`

```
apply(a, 3, rowSums)
```

#### data

```
a <- array(1:36, c(3, 4, 3))
```